# NestJS and GraphQL - TypeError: graphql_1.parse is not a function with minimal setup

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, apollo-server, nestjs

I am starting building my first API with Nest.
I am trying to add GraphQL and got an issue straight at the very beggining.

```
TypeError: graphql_1.parse is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\marek\dev\eparafie\api-nest\node_modules\apollo-server-core\node_modules\graphql-tools\src\stitching\introspectSchema.ts:7:48)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\marek\dev\eparafie\api-nest\node_modules\apollo-server-core\node_modules\graphql-tools\src\stitching\index.ts:2:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
```

I have so far just UsersModule and in its folder I have users.graphql file:

```
type Mutation {
    createUser(createUserInput: CreateUserInput): User
}

type User {
    id: Int
    email: String
    password: String
}
input CreateUserInput {
    email: String
    password: String
}
```

I also have simple resolver:

```
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { Mutation, Resolver } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { Body } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateUserDto } from '../dto/CreateUserDto';

@Resolver('User')
export class UserResolver {
  constructor(
    private readonly userService: UserService,
  ) {}

  @Mutation()
  async createUser(@Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
    return await this.userService.create(createUserDto);
  }
}
```

My app.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { Connection } from 'typeorm';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { UserService } from './user/user.service';
import { RolesService } from './auth/roles.service';
import { MembershipsService } from './auth/memberships.service';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
import { join } from 'path';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      typePaths: ['./**/*.graphql'],
      definitions: {
        path: join(process.cwd(), 'src/graphql.ts'),
      },
    }),
    UserModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService,
    UserService,
    RolesService,
    MembershipsService,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private readonly connection: Connection) {}
}
```

UserModule if it matters:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { User } from './user.entity';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { UserResolver } from './user.resolver';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])],
  providers: [UserService, UserResolver],
  controllers: [],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

Dependencies versions:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^5.3.9",
    "@nestjs/core": "^5.3.10",
    "@nestjs/graphql": "^5.4.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^5.2.2",
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.1.0",
    "graphql": "^14.0.2",
    "graphql-tools": "^4.0.0",
    "pg": "^7.4.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.7",
    "typescript": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/testing": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.1",
    "@types/node": "^10.7.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.5",
    "jest": "^23.5.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.3",
    "prettier": "^1.14.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "supertest": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-jest": "^23.1.3",
    "ts-loader": "^4.4.2",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.5.0",
    "tslint": "5.11.0",
    "webpack": "^4.16.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  },
```

src/graphql.ts should be generated from my graphql files right? Or I am missing something?
Documentation is not 100% clear about that, but it looks like resolver and graphql with types are required and it should be fine.
I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: Please add the stack trace of the error to the question.

Comment: done. Sorry, I was pretty sure I did it

Comment: Looks like something is going wrong with the `graphql` module loading.  I tried briefly to reproduce the problem and was unsuccessful.  Can you share a repository that reproduces the problem for you?

Comment: @MattMcCutchen I've same problem here.

Comment: @AbhinandanN.M. OK; if you can provide a repository, I'll be able to investigate.

Comment: Just followed instruction on this page on a clean new installation of nestjs from cli. https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/quick-start

It looks like the problem is in upstream graphqljs package.

Answer (score 1):

Change the filename of typings to something other than `graphql.ts`.

Like this

```
definitions: {
    path: join(process.cwd(), 'src/gql.ts'),
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I think changing output to class fixed my problem:

```
definitions: {
  path: join(process.cwd(), 'src/graphql.schema.ts'),
  outputAs: 'class',
},
```

(and delete old autogenerated files before start server with new code)

another thing to mention is to add this file to nodemon exceptions (at `nodemon.json` in root folder) to avoid reloading loop in development mode (when you use `npm run start:dev`)

```
{
  ...
  "ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/graphql.schema.ts"],
  ...
}
```

Comment: No. Changing the name from graphql.ts to graphql.schema.ts fixed your problem.